# Application form for visitor visa to Malta

Tags: visas, malta, kenya, ethiopian-citizens

What is the link to the online application form for an Ethiopian citizen wanting to apply for a visitor visa to Malta from Kenya?

Comment: Also related site: https://identitymalta.com

Answer (score 9):

If you are resident in Kenya the [Austrian Embassy](https://identitymalta.com/where-to-apply/) handles visa applications for Malta. In theory - they in turn have subcontracted the administration to [VFS](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Austria/kenya/). The VFS link is to a page where a form may be downloaded:

[image: VFS form]